# Using for loop to find the biggest number in an array

Tags: c#

I'm a begginer in c# and I'm trying to solve problems and exercises, what I have to do is write a method that compares the jump height of a jumper to the height of the hurdles, if the jump height is equal to or greater than the biggest hurdle, the method should return true. The heights of the hurdles are imputed in the form of an array, and the jump height is an integer.
The code I wrote was:

```
public static bool hurdleJump(int[] hurdles, int jumpHeight)
{
    int height= 0;
    for(int i = 0; i == hurdles.Length; i++)
    {
        if(hurdles[i] > height)
            height = hurdles[i];
    }

    if(jumpHeight >= height)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I used a for loop to find the biggest value inside of the array and then compared that to the int, but this code doesn't work with some arrays and I have no idea why, what am I missing?

Comment: `i == hurdles.Length`, this should be `i<hurdles.Length`.

Comment: An array having `n` items will have valid indices from `0` to `n - 1` (which counts `n` in total). Your loop shouldn't enter if `i` is equals to `n`. (You enters the loop from `0` to `n` which counts `n+1`, and you only have `n` item).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is not running because of the condition;

```
for(int i = 0; i == hurdles.Length; i++)
```

You must use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hurdles.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, much simple than using a loop:

```
public static bool hurdleJump(int[] hurdles, int jumpHeight)
{
    return jumpHeight >= hurdles.Max();
}
```